# VB.NET XML Literals Parsing

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-literals

If I have a text stored in db, file, resource does not matter:

```
<code><%= Integer.MaxValue %></code>
```

Is there a way to do this:

```
Dim el As XElement = XElement.Parse({variable containing text above})
```

and to have it evaluate the expression Integer.MaxValue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no. Compiler knows how to parse this and replaces your source code with something that looks like one would do in C# code.

Test code:

```
Dim source As String = "a,s,d,f"
Dim ar As String() = source.Split(","c)
Dim el As XElement = <code>
                         <%= From s In ar Select s + "22" %>
                     </code>
```

Reflected code:

```
Dim VB$CG$t_i4$S0 As Integer
Dim ar As String() = "a,s,d,f".Split(New Char() { ","c })
Dim VB$t_ref$S0 As New XElement(XName.Get("code", ""))
VB$t_ref$S0.Add(ar.Select(Of String, String)(New Func(Of String, String)(AddressOf Test._Lambda$__1)))
Dim el As XElement = VB$t_ref$S0
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the final answer. Would you mind saying how you learned this?

Comment: I used reflector to decompile my assembly and look what compiler did with my code. You can find it at http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Answer (score 1):

Not easily. The closest you could get it to use CodeDOM to generate some code - you'll need to produce a wrapper module and a `Function` with `Return`, then put the expression from the database into that `Return` - compile it (and check for compile errors), run it, and see the result. All in all, this would be very slow.

Comment: Do you know of any articles or resources that would help one wanting to attempt such a thing?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx covers CodeDOM. It doesn't specifically cover XML literals, though, since that's a VB-specific feature, so you'd need to use a literal expression - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codesnippetexpression.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think they key is understanding how embedded expressions work.  I've asked this as [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381182/how-are-vb-net-xml-embedded-expressions-implemented).